# Python old-style class __getattr__: "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm implementing a simple class to represent a 2D vector. Here's are the relevant bits:

```
class Vector:
  def __init__( self, x, y ):
    self.vec_repr = x, y

  def __add__( self, other ):
    new_x = self.x + other.x
    new_y = self.y + other.y
    return Vector( new_x, new_y )

  def __getattr__( self, name ):
    if name == "x":
      return self.vec_repr[0]
    elif name == "y":
      return self.vec_repr[1]
```

Later on, I have something like:

```
a = Vector( 1, 1 )
b = Vector( 2, 2 )
a + b
```

I get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. This is especially strange because the error is not marked as being on any particular line, so I don't know where to look!

Very strange, so I did some experimentation, and discovered that it occurs on the line `a+b`. Also, when I re-work the class to be as follows:

```
class Vector:
  def __init__( self, x, y ):
    self.x, self.y = x, y

  def __add__( self, other ):
    new_x = self.x + other.x
    new_y = self.y + other.y
    return Vector( new_x, new_y )
```

The error vanishes!

I see that there are lots of questions about an error similar to this - all seem to involve some function name being overwritten somewhere by a variable, but I don't see where this is happening!

As another clue, when I change the default return type of `__getattr__()` to something else - str, for example - the error morphs into `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Any ideas as to what's going on? Is there some behavior of `__getattr__()` that I don't understand?

Comment: Not reproducible in 3.8; `__getattr__` is only tried *after* the normal lookup. I could have sworn it always worked that way, but I will do more investigation.

Comment: **Note:** This *only* applies to old-style classes, which are no longer available in Python 3. In Python 2, use `class Vector(object): …` to define a new-style class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that your `__getattr__` doesn't return anything for attributes other than `x` and `y` and doesn't raise an AttributeError.  Hence when the `__add__` method is looked up, `__getattr__` returns `None` and hence your error.

You could fix this by making `__getattr__` return values for other attributes. In fact you have to ensure that `__getattr__` calls the method from its superclass for all attributes that are not handled. But really `__getattr__` is the wrong thing to use here. It should be used sparingly, and when there aren't more obvious, higher level solutions available. For example, `__getattr__` is essential for dynamic dispatch. But in your case, the `x` and `y` values are well known and well defined before the code runs.

The right solution is to make `x` and `y` properties and not implement `__getattr__` at all.

```
@property
def x(self):
    return self.vec_repr[0]

@property
def y(self):
    return self.vec_repr[1]
```

Comment: and just for the complete picture, it tried to call `__coerce__`

Comment: @yi_H I'm not familiar with `__coerce__`, but I can guess what it would do, and why it would be called!

Comment: Ooh. Wow, thanks. I thought that it falls back on __getattr__() when it doesn't find the attribute elsewhere. Well, this is hugely embarrassing.

Comment: Even a simple `a` fails as there is no `__repr__`.

Comment: I'm just saying that not only `a+b` fails but `a` as well as the default `__repr__` is shadowed by the `__getattr__` bug.

Comment: @yi_H OK, I see what you mean!